# Passing string from iphone app to osx app

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, bluetooth, wifi

I have an cocoa os x application done. But i have create a small iOS app that will run in a iPhone 4 and i want send some chars or strings to send commands to the OSX app.

It's important to say that the iPhone user will stay near the macbook laptop.

Whats the best way to do this?

My first idea was to use Bluetooth but Bluetooth core api dont work on iPhone 4. There is another way to do this over Bluetooth or only over wifi? If the only way to do this is over wifi how can i do that?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this over WiFi, there is this open source network library called [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) that will simplify your task.  It works on both Mac and iDevices platforms.  The library comes with sample projects.  Good luck.